# Copy a selected drop down value from one select box to another

Tags: php, jquery, forms

Simplified, I have a form that generate select boxes based on a mysql query.

```
$i = 0;
while($res= mysql_fetch_assoc($sql2))
echo "  <div class='span1'>";
echo "      <input name='orderNo[$i]' type='text' id='orderNo[$i]' value='$orderNo' class='input-small' onclick='populateorderNo()' />";
echo "  </div>";

echo "  <div class='span1'>";
echo "      <select name='methodOfPay[$i]' id='methodOfPay[$i]' class='input-small' >";
echo "      <option value=''>&nbsp;</option>";
echo "      <option value='On Bill'>On Bill</option>";
echo "      <option value='Customer C.C'>Customer C.C</option>";
echo "      <option value='Company G.C'>Company G.C</option>";
echo "      </select>";
echo "  </div>";
++$i;
}
```

What I am trying to do is copy the selected option on methodOFPay[0] to the succeeding methodOfPay[]'s. I was able to do it using an onclick function for orderNo, but I can't figure out how to apply the same theory to a select box. Here is my js code for the simple text box copy. For now, it's always going to be the first row copying to the succeeding rows.

```
var orderno = 0;
function populateorderNo(){
var copyorderNo = document.getElementById('orderNo[0]');
document.getElementById('orderNo[' + orderno + ']').value = copyorderNo.value;
orderno += 1;
```

}

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you very much, as a newbie, I am learning a lot from this site and all the answers I have received.

Comment: Are you trying to make it work so that if the user clicks on the drop down menu, say for instance they click **On Bill** then all of the drop down menu's will have **On Bill** selected?

Comment: at the moment that is the idea, whatever is selected on methodOfPay[0] will copy to the other methodOfPay

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using straight JavaScript you can use [`onchange`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.onchange). In jQuery, you can use [`.change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/).

**Straight JavaScript Method**

PHP

```
echo "      <select name='methodOfPay[$i]' id='methodOfPay[$i]' class='input-small' onchange='myOnChangeFunction()' >";
 ...
echo "      </select>";
```

JS

```
function myOnChangeFunction() {
    // Get value and set other selects
}
```

**jQuery Method ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cbL6n/1/))**

JS

```
$('select[id^="methodOfPay"]').change(function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    $('select[id^="methodOfPay"]').not($(this)).val(value);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I've changed your code slightly for ease of demonstration but the theory is still the same.

The main thing to note is the use of **count($orderNo)** in the javascript

This will work better with jQuery and regular expressions as was shown in Ruben Infante's example

```
<?php

for ($i = 0; $i < 10; ++$i) {
    $orderNo[$i] = $i;
}

?>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Hello</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function populateorderNo() {
                var copyorderNo = document.getElementById('orderNo[0]');
                for (var i = 0; i < <?php echo count($orderNo); ?>; i++) {
                    document.getElementById("orderNo["+i+"]").value = copyorderNo.value;
                }
            }

            function changeSelectBox() {
                var selectBox = document.getElementById('methodOfPay[0]');
                for (var i = 0; i < <?php echo count($orderNo); ?>; i++) {
                    document.getElementById('methodOfPay['+i+']').value = selectBox.value;
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        Hello
        <?php foreach ($orderNo as $r): ?>
            <div class='span1'>
            <input name='orderNo[<?php echo $r;?>]' type='text' id='orderNo[<?php echo $r;?>]' value='<?php echo $r;?>' class='input-small' onchange='populateorderNo();' />
            </div>

            <div class='span1'>
            <select name='methodOfPay[<?php echo $r; ?>]' id='methodOfPay[<?php echo $r;?>]' class='input-small' onchange='changeSelectBox();' >
            <option value=''>&nbsp;</option>
            <option value='On Bill'>On Bill</option>
            <option value='Customer C.C'>Customer C.C</option>
            <option value='Company G.C'>Company G.C</option>
            </select>
            </div>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </body>
</html>
```